# Footable - two values in one cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, cell, footable

I use a Footable table, but I have a problem with values. I need to show in one cell two values.

But i cant add two values.
I use Ajax for loading data

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.table').footable({
        "columns": [
                    { "name": "PartID", "title":"PartID", "visible":false },
                    {"formatter": function(value){
                        return //I'm thinking this is where the code would go to join the next 3 columns? in the format ##.###.##
                    }},
                    { "name": "PartCategory", "title": "PC" },
                    { "name": "PartNumber1", "title": "PN1" },
                    { "name": "PartNumber2", "title": "PN2",  },
}
                ],
        "rows": $.get('rows.json')
    });
});
```

**PartNumber1 and PartNumber2 must be on one cell, but how?**

[Footable Plugin](https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/index.html)
[Footable Ajax table](https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/examples/advanced/ajax.html)

Comment: You can tweak rows.json data after getting it, means go over each row and append two fields that you want to show under single column

Comment: Thank you. I would like to find another way, but I think there is only one